Como puedo poner los labels encima de los input?
Tengo este html:
<form>
    <div class="formSorteo">
        <label class="labelSorteo">Nombre organizador</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <label class="labelSorteo">Fecha celebracion</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <label class="labelSorteo">Presupuesto</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
    </div>
</form>

Y este codigo css:
.formCompleto {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

.formSorteo {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.formSorteo input {
  display: inline;
}

.formSorteo label {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}

Y no se porque se me están juntando los labels con los inputs cuando quiero que los label queden encima de los input algo asi:


Lo primero es que tienes flex-direction: column; cuando debería ser flex-direction: row; u omitir el valor ya que por default es row. Y el truco para que el input quede debajo del label es setearlo como display:block;, de esta manera ocupa toda la fila, obligando a que salte a la fila de abajo
Además, agrego unas pequeñas sugerencias a tu autorespuesta
1.- No necesitas un div debajo del form, el form puede actuar perfectamente como un contenedor
2.- No necesitas un div para contener el label+input, el label tambien puede actuar como un contenedor. Además, de esta manera te ahorras usar el atributo for, ya que el input al estar dentro del label queda automáticamente referenciado


.formSorteo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.formSorteo input{
  display:block;
}
<form class="formSorteo">
  <label class="labelSorteo">Nombre organizador
     <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  </label>

  <label class="labelSorteo">Fecha celebracion
     <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  </label>

  <label class="labelSorteo">Presupuesto
     <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  </label>
</form>




Finalmente conseguí resolverlo de la siguiente manera:
Descubrí que la etiqueta label contiene un atributo llamado for que se encarga de hacer referencia al input gracias al atributo name, aparte tambien para poder gestionar mejor los labels y los inputs juntos tuve que añadir un contenedor div a cada uno de ellos; Con todos estos cambios el html quedara asi:
<form>
        <div class="formSorteo">
            <div>
                <label for="Nombre organizador" class="labelSorteo">Nombre organizador</label>
                <input type="text" name="Nombre organizador" id="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Fecha celebracion" class="labelSorteo">Fecha celebracion</label>
                <input type="text" name="Fecha celebracion" id="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Presupuesto" class="labelSorteo">Presupuesto</label>
                <input type="text" name="Presupuesto" id="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

y ahora lo único que nos falta seria ajustar el css para que quede con la posicion correcta:
.formSorteo {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80%; 
  margin: auto;
  gap: 15px;
}

.formSorteo div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  gap: 5px;
}

